# I want to change the direction of the bar in a swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a bar containing mutual data of two users. I want it to be like this image:

[image]

I also used the `Rectangle()` shape here. But the bar starts to fill up after 0.5, it seems empty before that. What should I do here?

The code I wrote is as follows:

```swift
 HStack{
          ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            Rectangle()
                  .trim(from:0.1, to:0.6)
                .fill(Color.init( red: 0.965, green: 0.224, blue: 0.49))
                .frame(width: 55, height: 11)
            Text(String(nowduelList.user1StepCount))
                    .font(.system(size: 8))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
             ZStack(alignment: .trailing){
                 Rectangle()
                     .trim(from:0, to: 0.8)
                     .fill(Color.init( red: 0.208, green: 0.231, blue: 0.314))
                       .frame(width: 55, height: 11)
                Text(String(nowduelList.user2StepCount))
                    .font(.system(size: 8))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
        }
```

And this is an image of my `View`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code you can modify and optimize the code as you want.

```
struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX/1.2, y: 0))
        return path
    }
}


struct LeadingTriangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX/1.2-rect.maxX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: 0))
        return path
    }
}

var body: some View {
    
    HStack{
        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 30)
                .overlay(
                    Triangle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                )
            Text(String(23.32))
                .font(.system(size: 8))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing){
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 30)
                .overlay(
                    LeadingTriangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                )
            
            Text(String(23.32))
                .font(.system(size: 8))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it answers the question, either with text or comments. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: Here first I took Rectangle() and on that, I applied an overlay named triangle.
Now in this triangle, I took a rectangle shape, and using CGRect I applied coordinates on all points of the rectangle. CGRect is a structure that contains the location and dimensions of a rectangle. So we can make modifications on rectange as we want.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the first view to achieve this:

```
    HStack(spacing: -5) {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            Rectangle()
                .trim(from:0, to:0.8) // << Same as second view
                .rotation(Angle(degrees: 180)) // << Rotation
                .fill(Color.init( red: 0.965, green: 0.224, blue: 0.49))
                .frame(width: 55, height: 11)
            
            Text(String(951))
                .font(.system(size: 8))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing){
            Rectangle()
                .trim(from:0, to: 0.8)
                .fill(Color.init( red: 0.208, green: 0.231, blue: 0.314))
                .frame(width: 55, height: 11)
            Text(String(231))
                .font(.system(size: 8))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
```